# Laravel: Storage::disk('public') points to https://localhost/ in production server, not in dev

Tags: php, laravel

My development server is called `jb.test` my production server is (let's say) `jb.com`. I'm uploading images using Livewire's methods:

```
$url = $this->photo->store('ranker', 'public');
```

According to documentation [here](https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/file-uploads). I used the second parameter "public" to use the configured public storage.

When I extract the image in the development server I use:

```
Storage::disk('public')->url($o->imagen_url)
```

The `$o` variable is the object that is storing the image (comes from a `@foreach` in a Blade)

This produces `http://jb.test/storage/ranker/.....jpg` as expected, and displays the image. Now, this very exact code, in the production server produces `https://localhost/storage/ranker/.....jpg` and of course, it gets no image

So... why this happens? is it a wrong configuration?

Comment: Did you changed APP_URL in .env?

Comment: Right, Looks like you have changed APP_URL in the .env file. Also, check your APP_ENV variable

Comment: Right, Looks like you have changed APP_URL in the .env file. Also, check your APP_ENV variable

Comment: You were right gentlemen, the `.env` was defective. I changed it and got the correct address. Unfortunately, I'm still getting a 404 (but from the correct domain)